# Issue reading hidden column using VBA in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently having issues with a Macro I am programming for Excel 2013 regarding reading hidden columns. I am trying to utilize Column A as a row of unique keys to allow me to quickly develop logic that hides and shows a row based on the key value in column A. When I hide column A manually in the sheet for visual purposes I am then unable to read from that column, aka my code returns an error. If I show the column the code executes clearly. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
Public Sub hideRow(findId As String, sheetName As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim hideThisRowNum As Integer

    'Get Last Row
    lastRow = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find ID
    With Worksheets(sheetName).Range("a1:a1000") 'This needs to be A1 to AxlDown
        Set foundCell = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=findId,     LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    'Get Row # to Hide

    hideThisRowNum = Val(foundCell.Row)

    'Hide row
    Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(hideThisRowNum).Hidden = True

    'Set Add To Action Plan = No
    Worksheets(sheetName).Range("G" & hideThisRowNum).Value = "No"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the .Find() call.  Using `LookIn:=xlValues` won't find hidden cells.  Change it to `LookIn:=xlFormulas` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the problem. You saved me an hour or so of confusion as I am brand new to VB.